# Where exactly is the file linux/kernel.h?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I am reading through Salzman's Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide, and I was wondering about where the file linux/kernel.h is located. I couldn't find it with `find`. Or rather the files I found did not have any `printk` priority macros in them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `linux/kernel.h` header which gets used for module builds is the header which is [part of the kernel source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/kernel.h). When modules are built in the kernel source tree, that’s the version which is used.

For external module builds, the build process looks for the header in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux/sched.h`. That file is provided by kernel header packages, *e.g.* on Debian derivatives, the `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` package.

The `/usr/include/linux/kernel.h` is intended for user processes, not for kernel modules.

The `printk` priority macros now live in [`linux/printk.h`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/printk.h) and [`linux/kern_levels.h`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/kern_levels.h). I’m guessing you’re reading [the original guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/), which is based on the 2.6 kernel series; for modern kernels you should read [the updated guide](https://code.freedombone.net/bashrc/LKMPG) (currently for [5.6.7](https://code.freedombone.net/bashrc/LKMPG/src/master/5.6.7)).

Answer (score 2):

On my Mint 18.x system with the `build-essential` BUT not any full source tree installed -

```
user@localhost:~ $ locate kernel.h | grep \/kernel.h$
/usr/include/linux/kernel.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21/include/linux/kernel.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21/include/uapi/linux/kernel.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic/include/config/debug/kernel.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic/include/config/firmware/in/kernel.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-53/include/linux/kernel.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-53/include/uapi/linux/kernel.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic/include/config/debug/kernel.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic/include/config/firmware/in/kernel.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-53/include/linux/kernel.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-53/include/uapi/linux/kernel.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-53-generic/include/config/debug/kernel.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-53-generic/include/config/firmware/in/kernel.h
```

Per Jeff's comment on your question, I would assume that *most* times `/usr/include/linux/kernel.h` is what will be used,

I'm sure if you extract a kernel tree tarball it may have another copy in its directory structure as well. A quick check shows them all as being different sizes... or empty files.

Comment: `locate '*/kernel.h'` is how you can get `locate` to match the exact filename (also, `locate` supports regexes as well). (I'm assuming `mlocate` given it's Linux Mint)

Answer (score 1):

the answer to this might significantly depend on the linux distribution... SUSE/SLES vs RHEL/Centos/Fedora vs debian vs mint and so on,

and could it also differ based on RPM flavors of linux distros vs debian ?

in any case my experience is mostly with SLES version 11.4, 
and for that I can vouch for

```
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/kernel.h

where for me   /usr/src/linux -> /usr/src/linux-3.0.101-108.21

uname -r    for me returns 3.0.101-108.21-default
```

as I update the kernel to newer versions, the soft link changes accordingly  along with kernel.h.  I think it is safe to say if you are looking for the **kernel module** version of `kernel.h` it will be under some folder related to `uname -r` and be part of the **kernel source** package for your linux distribution.